# All RAM is used by virtualbox after launching ubuntu 20.04

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I have Oracle Virtualbox on my windows 11. I configured instance to have 20GB RAM, use 8 CPUs and to have 100GB memory. I installed there ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The problem is, that I can't use it, as it's lagging or even doesn't respond. I checked my windows task manager and 97% memory is used, mostly by Virtualbox. I wonder what's wrong. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The usual recommendation is to never allocated more than 50% RAM to the virtual machine. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have 32GB RAM. Ok, I will try using 12GB on Virtualbox

Comment: Even 12GB is too much probably, but depends on what you're doing in the VM. Keep in mind that resources allocated to the VMs are resources *removed* from the host while the VMs are running. You don't want to give the VMs resources they won't be using anyway.

Comment: Lastly, this is a generic and very basic virtualization question that has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Windows problem when using Windows software... not our problem to solve since the answer is not going to be something in Ubuntu https://superuser.com/ is more appropriate

Comment: For your information, the minimum recommended RAM for Ubuntu desktop is 4GB.

Comment: Just my two cents, I have encountered similar problems when running windows 10 on my Ubuntu 21.10 host.

Comment: You have 32 gig of RAM and the question says you told the VM to use 100 gig.

Comment: @David The "100GB memory" refers to the virtual drive, not RAM.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Then the question needs to be edited.

Comment: @David Arguably it's memory as well. That said, since many decades ago, indeed we tend to use "memory" only in the context of "Random Access Memory".

Comment: I think the problem is that oracle virtualbox isn't compatibile with windows 11. On vmware everything works properly.